# Problem with sending text attachment in Perl

Tags: perl, smtp, email-attachments

I have a procedure to send mails as this:

```
sub SendMail {
    my $subject = shift;
    my @message = @_;
    my $sender;

    my $MIME_BOUNDARY = '====Multipart.Boundary.689464861147414354====';
    my $now = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime);
    my @addresses = split(",", $ENV{ADMIN_MAIL});
    my $sender = $ENV{USER} || $ENV{USERNAME};
    $sender .= "\@" . hostname();
    my $smtp = Net::SMTP->new($ENV{MAILHOST} || 'mailhost', Debug => 1);
    unless ( $smtp ) {
        die "Error while sending notification mail. Not connected to SMTP server.";
    }
    $smtp->mail( $addresses[0] );
    $smtp->recipient( @addresses );
    $smtp->data;
    $smtp->datasend("From: $sender\n");
    $smtp->datasend("To: " . join(",", @addresses) . "\n");
    $smtp->datasend("Subject: $subject\n");
    $smtp->datasend("Date: " . strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z", localtime) . "\n");     

    if ( @log_messages ) {
        $smtp->datasend("Mime-Version: 1.0\n");
        $smtp->datasend("Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$MIME_BOUNDARY\"\n");
        $smtp->datasend("This is a multipart message in MIME format.\n");
        $smtp->datasend("--$MIME_BOUNDARY\n");
    }

    $smtp->datasend("Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n");
    $smtp->datasend("Content-Disposition: quoted-printable\n");
    $smtp->datasend("\n");
    foreach ( @message ) { $smtp->datasend("$_\n") }
    $smtp->datasend("\n\n");
    $smtp->datasend("Message from " . hostname() . " (PID=$$) sent by 'LogDumper.pl' at $now");
    $smtp->datasend("\n");

    if ( @log_messages ) {
        $smtp->datasend("\n");
        $smtp->datasend("--$MIME_BOUNDARY\n");
        $smtp->datasend("Content-Type: text/plain; name=\"logs.txt\"\n");
        $smtp->datasend("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"logs.txt\"\n");
        $smtp->datasend("\n");
        foreach ( @log_messages ) { $smtp->datasend("$_\n") }
        $smtp->datasend("\n");
        $smtp->datasend("--$MIME_BOUNDARY--\n");
    }

    $smtp->dataend;
    $smtp->quit;

}
```

The procedure works fine with plain text mails, i.e. empty `@log_messages`. However, if I try to attach a text file

```
my @log_messages;
push @log_messages, "Line 1";
push @log_messages, "Line 2";
SendMail("The Subject", "The Message");
```

then the mail is not sent.

Debug output is this:

```
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x7a78a40)<<< 354 Start mail input; end with <CRLF>.<CRLF>
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x7a78a40)>>> From: Domscheit@xxxxx
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x7a78a40)>>> To: wernfried.domscheit@xxxxx.xxx
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x7a78a40)>>> Subject: The Suject
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x7a78a40)>>> Date: Mo, 01 Okt 2018 10:15:57 W. Europe Daylight Time
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x7a78a40)>>> Mime-Version: 1.0
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x7a78a40)>>> Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="====Multipart.Boundary.689464861147414354===="
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x7a78a40)>>> This is a multipart message in MIME format.
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x7a78a40)>>> --====Multipart.Boundary.689464861147414354====
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x7a78a40)>>> Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x7a78a40)>>> Content-Disposition: quoted-printable
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x7a78a40)>>> The Message
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x7a78a40)>>> Message from xxxxx (PID=8072) sent by 'LogDumper.pl' at 2018-10-01 10:15:54
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x7a78a40)>>> --====Multipart.Boundary.689464861147414354====
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x7a78a40)>>> Content-Type: text/plain; name="logs.txt"
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x7a78a40)>>> Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="logs.txt"
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x7a78a40)>>> Line 1
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x7a78a40)>>> Line 2
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x7a78a40)>>> --====Multipart.Boundary.689464861147414354====--
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x7a78a40)>>> .
Net::SMTP: Unexpected EOF on command channel at C:\Developing\Source\LogDumper.pl line 1271.
```

Apparently there is a missing or needless `\n`. I tried to put it almost everywhere but I don't get it working.

**Update:**

Actually it is working when I execute the script on Linux but not on my Windows development PC.

Comment: Why don't you use a higher-level module that does the heavy lifting for you? [MIME::Lite](http://p3rl.org/MIME::Lite), [Email::Sender](http://p3rl.org/Email::Sender)...

Comment: A couple of notes, in hope that they may help. (1) I find `$smpt->datasend();` in my code (written too long ago to remember), after sections like body.  (2) After sending `@messages` you print two `\n` while after `@log_messages` there is one.

Comment: @choroba "_MIME::Lite is not recommended by its current maintainer_" (docs). Alternatives are given of course, but I looked once for a solid emailer, which could do just enough for me, and ended up using `Net::SMTP`.

Comment: @zdim, yes but two `\n` are only to beautify the common footer line

Comment: @zdim There are plans to revive MIME::Lite a bit, see [here](https://github.com/rjbs/MIME-Lite/pull/12).

Comment: Maybe try MIME::Entity?

Comment: As stated by @zdim, "MIME::Lite" is not recommended and apparently "Email::Sender" does not support attachments at all (did only a quick view at the docs)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit: [Email::Sender](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Sender) definitely supports attachment (the example in the synopsis uses Email::MIME to create the actual email). But you might look at [Email::Stuffer](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Stuffer). In my opinion, it's currently the easiest way to create and send email with Perl.

Comment: @choroba  Thank you for that information. It'd be nice to find something higher level, yet complete (and not too heavy).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is solved.

- It works on production server at Linux
- It works on development Windows PC when I am working in the office
- It does not work on Windows when I am working at home and connected via VPN - nasty security department...

Well, it is not really solved but for me it is working fine. I did not test (yet) whether it fails over VPN also for one of the higher-level packages.